# Why is FromBody modifier not needed for subsequent parameters?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

jQuery calling an mvc controller via ajax post.  This works, but why doesn't the 2nd parameter require the [FromBody] modifier also?

where itemList is an array of int and billingStatus is a string.

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateBillingLines", "BillingExceptions")',
        data: {
            lines: itemList,
            statusTo: billingStatus
        },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //test
        },
        error: function (xhr, txtStatus, err) {
            alert(txtStatus);
        }
 });
```

controller

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateBillingLines([FromBody] List<int> lines, string statusTo)
{
    string result = "";
    // logic here
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it's *not needed* (as you put it).  It's that it *can't* be used for subsequent parameters.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) explains why:

> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body...
> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a
> non-buffered stream that can only be read once